# Python: putting two Codepieces together

Tags: python, mysql

I have python code which reads an analog sensor from an raspberry_pi and further code which inserts data in my mysqldb. Each code is working alone. I want to put those two pieces of code together. My objective is to insert the temp and timestammp into the mysqldb.

First Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import spidev
import time
import os

# Open SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

# Function to read SPI data from MCP3008 chip
# Channel must be an integer 0-7
def ReadChannel(channel):
  adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
  return data

# Function to convert data to voltage level,
# rounded to specified number of decimal places.
def ConvertVolts(data,places):
  volts = (data * 3.3) / 1023
  volts = round(volts,places)
  return volts

# Function to calculate temperature from
# TMP36 data, rounded to specified
# number of decimal places.
def ConvertTemp(data,places):

  # ADC Value
  # (approx)  Temp  Volts
  #    0      -50    0.00
  #   78      -25    0.25
  #  155        0    0.50
  #  233       25    0.75
  #  310       50    1.00
  #  465      100    1.50
  #  775      200    2.50
  # 1023      280    3.30

  temp = ((data * 330)/1023)-50
  temp = round(temp,places)
  return temp

# Define sensor channels
light_channel = 0
temp_channel  = 1

# Define delay between readings
delay = 5

while True:

  # Read the light sensor data
  light_level = ReadChannel(light_channel)
  light_volts = ConvertVolts(light_level,2)

  # Read the temperature sensor data
  temp_level = ReadChannel(temp_channel)
  temp_volts = ConvertVolts(temp_level,2)
  temp       = ConvertTemp(temp_level,2)

  # Print out results
  print "--------------------------------------------"
  print("Light: {} ({}V)".format(light_level,light_volts))
  print("Temp : {} ({}V) {} deg C".format(temp_level,temp_volts,temp))

  # Wait before repeating loop
  time.sleep(delay)
```

and the second code:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.1.1.100", port=3306, user="schnickschnack", passwd="schnackschnick", db="visu")
    cursor = db.cursor()
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO temp (value) VALUES(%s)", (temp))
```

Comment: As a side note, `(temp)` is the same thing as `temp`; there is no reason to write it with the extra parentheses. If you're trying to make it a tuple, you need a comma, like `(temp,)`.

Answer (score 0):

Just… put it together:

```
# ...

# Print out results
print "--------------------------------------------"
print("Light: {} ({}V)".format(light_level,light_volts))
print("Temp : {} ({}V) {} deg C".format(temp_level,temp_volts,temp))

# Your extra code here to add temp to the database
db = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.1.1.100", port=3306, user="schnickschnack", passwd="schnackschnick", db="visu")
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO temp (value) VALUES(%s)", (temp))

# Wait before repeating loop
time.sleep(delay)
```

---

You might want to move the `db =` line outside the loop, so you connect to the database once, instead of over and over. Then again, especially if `delay` is pretty long, you might not. Assuming you do want that, it's simple: take that line, move it up above the `while True`, and dedent it to the first column.

Comment: Ive tried this but this error occures: 

    pi@zero-four ~ $ sudo python tmp.py 
    File "tmp.py", line 80
    time.sleep(delay)
    ^

Comment: @user3147852: If you don't show the actual error, I can't debug it for you. You can't paste a traceback into a comment here because of limitations of StackOverflow, but you can edit it into your question, or paste it somewhere like [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com) and post a link here.

Comment: @user3147852: However, given the inconsistent indentation of your question, I'm guessing the problem is that your attempt had inconsistent indentation and confused the interpreter. Maybe you don't understand Python's simple indentation rules, or maybe your editor is mixing tabs and spaces?

Answer (score 0):

Thank's for you help, now it works! i was confused with indents "function" which python use.
here ist the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import spidev
import time
import os
import MySQLdb

# Open SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

# Function to read SPI data from MCP3008 chip
# Channel must be an integer 0-7
def ReadChannel(channel):
  adc = spi.xfer2([1,(8+channel)<<4,0])
  data = ((adc[1]&3) << 8) + adc[2]
  return data

# Function to convert data to voltage level,
# rounded to specified number of decimal places.
def ConvertVolts(data,places):
  volts = (data * 3.3) / 1023
  volts = round(volts,places)
  return volts

# Function to calculate temperature from
# TMP36 data, rounded to specified
# number of decimal places.
def ConvertTemp(data,places):

  # ADC Value
  # (approx)  Temp  Volts
  #    0      -50    0.00
  #   78      -25    0.25
  #  155        0    0.50
  #  233       25    0.75
  #  310       50    1.00
  #  465      100    1.50
  #  775      200    2.50
  # 1023      280    3.30

  temp = ((data * 330)/1023)-50
  temp = round(temp,places)
  return temp


# Define sensor channels
light_channel = 0
temp_channel  = 1
 # Define delay between readings
delay = 5


while True:

  # Read the light sensor data
  light_level = ReadChannel(light_channel)
  light_volts = ConvertVolts(light_level,2)

  # Read the temperature sensor data
  temp_level = ReadChannel(temp_channel)
  temp_volts = ConvertVolts(temp_level,2)
  temp       = ConvertTemp(temp_level,2)

  # Print out results
  print "--------------------------------------------"
  print("Light: {} ({}V)".format(light_level,light_volts))
  print("Temp : {} ({}V) {} deg C".format(temp_level,temp_volts,temp))

  # Your extra code here to add temp to the database
  db = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.0.1.100", port=3306, user="12233", passwd="1212", db="visu")
  cursor = db.cursor()
  cursor.execute("INSERT INTO temp (value) VALUES(%s)", (temp))

  # Wait before repeating loop
  time.sleep(delay)
```